# Can drupal commerce products become cheaper to the customer when they order more?

Tags: commerce

I would like to set up a shop to sell custom made products, all variations on the same base product.
The greater the number of tasks I have to do to get the product ready, the more expensive the product.

Some of these task do not require set up time for an order, but some tasks do.

Can drupal commerce take calculate the cost per item for a variation per product and the costs per order and turn those in to a sell price (the only price) the customer can see, based on the number of products they want to order?

**Example:**

Let's say, the products are cubes.

I can make a cube out of wood or plastic.
I can finish them by just sanding them, or paint them, or cover them in fabric.

Just sanding them is the quickest and thus the cheapest. Painting takes more time and is more expensive. Black is more difficult to get right then white, so again, is more expensive.

But also, painting not only takes time for the painting itself, it takes setup time for the whole order AND for every layer.

I would like to configure the products so that I can include most of these price factors in to the price the customer sees in the shop as they are changing the number they may want to order.

Because my typical order quantity is between 1 and 10, those diferences make a big difference in the price.

Can this kind of calculations be done with drupal commerce out of the box or with contributed modules, or would this require coding?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're on Drupal 7 yes, I've done this with the Commerce Price Table module: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table

"This is a contributed module for Drupal Commerce that allows you to use a secondary price field to supply an alternate price for a product based on the quantity of that product on the line item. It also provides a field formatter to display the price/quantity values as a table."

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry I missed it. That seems to come closer than anything I found so far, in any system. 

If I make a kit from the base product plus options also defined as a product, can I make the quantity of each option result from the quantity of the base product?

So if 10 are ordered of the base product also 10 of the option are chosen?